# Opening PDF iOS Adobe Reader

Tags: ios6

I am trying to design a website for iPad. I "Add to Homescreen" the page from within Safari, and from then on it loads in full screen mode, so no toolbar appears, with the help of a simple meta tag

In full screen mode will load a PDF file from a link without issue, but the "Open In" option is no where to be found 
But if I were to navigate to the same PDF by clicking Safari, typing the page address, the option is there

My question, how can I make the "Open In" appear **OR**
Is there a way to open the file with a "**com.adobe.Adobe-Reader**" command

Regards,
Callum